# Do Steam achievements work with the GTA IV Downgrader?

Tags: mods, grand-theft-auto-iv

If I use the [GTA IV Downgrader](https://gtaforums.com/topic/976691-gta-iv-downgrader/) to downgrade the Steam version of Grand Theft Auto IV, will I still be able to earn Steam achievements on the older version?

Answer (score 2):

No, as the old versions don't know how to interact with Steam and give you achievements (old versions use the legacy Games for Windows Live achievements).